# main thread timer Vs Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, wcf

i have a windows service that starts a timer on the main thread. The timers job is to load an xml file to memory, do some processing on the values and save the results back to the file. The processing can take 10 minutes for example. (lets call this operation A)

I also have a thread that gets spawned via WCF on the same service which updates the xml file. (lets call this operation B)

What is happening is that Operation A is running and Operation B runs to completion before Operation A is completed. The end result being that operation A overwrites all the work that operation B completed.

So what i think i need to do is:

1. When Operation A is starting,If operation B is running, wait for
   operation B to complete then execute Operation A
2. When Operation B is started,If operation A is running, wait for
   operation A to complete then execute Operation B

if i could do this i wouldn't have a problem i think.

I hope this makes sense - 
Is my wait theory the best way to do this?
How can i do this in c# (or whatever the best method is)?

thanks
Damo

Comment: Use a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Comment: Nice never used that one before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily solved by using the `lock` statement in C#.

All you'll need is an instance of some object (the type doesn't matter) that both sections of code have access to.

```
public static void MethodA(object lockObject)
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        //code that needs to be accessed by just one thread
    }
}

public static void MethodB(object lockObject)
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        //code that needs to be accessed by just one thread
    }
}
```

If both of these operations are being fired from a timer you should ensure that adding extra waiting doesn't push you to the point where executing the code takes longer than the interval on the timer; if you do you'll end up firing off new code quicker than they finish and there will always be more and more instances running.  (That is solved by having it do nothing if a previous task is still running.)

Comment: To my knowledge, this even works with strings. So you could for example use `lock("critical-section"){ ... }` in both MethodA and MethodB. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @manuFS: You can, but you shouldn't.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182290.aspx

Comment: @manuFS You most certainly **do not want to do that**.  There are several reasons.  First off, strings have the whole interning business, and for that reason (since you don't know for sure whether or not it's enabled, whether or not the compiler chooses to use it anyway, and how it chooses to do so) you can't *rely* on it doing anything.  On top of that, nothing would be preventing anyone else from accessing the same object instance (if it's interned) so you could end up with several separate sections of code using the same lock.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful. for example, I once implemented a cache with it: `Do(string input){ lock(input){ if(dict.HasKey(input)) return dict[input]; /... costly calculation here.. return dict[input]=calculatedValue; }`

Comment: @manuFS Like I said, you **do not want to do that**.  It won't reliably work.  Two strings generated at runtime, even if equal, won't have the same instances, and so won't have separate locks, but since the values are equal they'll be accessing the same dictionary value.  The fact that compile time literals are interned simply gives you a false sense that it's working through your (apparently insufficient) testing.

Comment: @manuFS So you wanted to create random race conditions and inconsistent errors in which certain strings would work as intended while others weren't based on arbitrary conditions not predicable at runtime?  I really hope it's a program I never need to interact with.

Comment: thanks, ill take a look at this tomorrow and revert as to how i get on